# Convert slider/carousel to pager while switching from Desktop to Mobile View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a slider/carousel like the one below on left - Desktop view.

I would like it to be switching to Pager based slider on mobile screens - like the one on the right side.

[image]

I have used this script for desktop slider - 
https://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/Simplest-3D-Image-Carousel-Plugin-For-jQuery-Carousel-js.html

Any help will be great, Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with [**media queries**](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)?

Comment: Yes, I am. Just not sure how to trigger 2 different kind of sliders on desktop and mobile, one with arrows and one with pager only. Can it be done by editing the slider JavaScript I used for desktop version?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use 2 plugins for this. As far as I can tell there is no "pager" option for the plugin you are using. And then, using JavaScript you should destroy current plugin and initialize new one. Which could also be a problem since I don't see any sort of `destroy` method for your plugin. So ok, it would look something like this.

```js
function init3DSlider() {
    $('.your-container').carousel({
        your: 'options'
    })
}
function initPagerSlider() {
    $('.your-container').somePagerPlugin({
        // ...your options
    })
}

// Function for checking which slider should turn on.
function turnOnSliderDependingOnResolution () {
    if(window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
        init3DSlider()
        // ...somehow destroy pager slider
    } else {
        initPagerSlider()
        // ...somehow destroy 3d slider
    }
}

// Run turnOnSliderDependingOnResolution function on window resize.
window.addEventListener('resize', turnOnSliderDependingOnResolution)
```

Since this 3d slider doesn't have `destroy` method, try using this: http://ub4.underblob.com/remove-jquery-plugin-instance/

Or you can use a more simple solution, and that is to duplicate your slider, initialize both sliders (3D and pager). And then using CSS media queries you would hide one or the other.

Not exactly optimal but it will work.

Comment: Thanks @idoric, this works well! I have added two different plugins as advised. Can you please guide how to add destroy method for 3d slider from the link? Shall I place below code directly or need to modify it in any manner? --- var destroyCrappyPlugin = function($elem, eventNamespace) {
    var isInstantiated  = !! $.data($elem.get(0));
 
    if (isInstantiated) {
        $.removeData($elem.get(0));
        $elem.off(eventNamespace);
        $elem.unbind('.' + eventNamespace);
    }
};

Comment: One more thing - none of the slider is working currently on page load but if I resize the browser window relevant slider is showing up.